# How do you access a base controller property from a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a `CurrentUser` property in my base controller which all other controllers inherit from. I would like to be able to access the `CurrentUser` property in all my views including partials but have not found a way to do this in aspnet core 6. You used to be able to case the `Controller` object to the type of your base controller but I don't see an equivalent.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public DBUser CurrentUser {...}
}

public class SomeChildController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index
    {
        ...
    }
}

_layout.cshtml
...
<body>
    <header>
        <partial name="_mainNav" />
    </header>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
...

index.cshtml
<p>Nothing here</p>

_mainNav.cshtml Share view
<p>Your user = @controller.CurrentUser.Name</p>
```

Comment: in asp.net core there's no `ViewContext.Controller`, so when you want to get `CurrentUser` in partial view, you may set the CurrentUser as a property of ViewBag, then in the controller, set `ViewBag.temp = this.CurrentUser;` and in partical view, get it like `<p>Your user = @ViewBag.temp</p>`

Comment: `CurrentUser.Name` refers to the user-model and not to the `UserController`. So it might be enough to write just `<p>Your user = CurrentUser.Name</p>`